# How to recover accidentily deleted LUKS partition table?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, luks

### The problem

I've accidently deleted a LUKS partition by pressing the red button in the bottom right corner on one of my external hard drives.

[image]

Now it just says "Free Space":

[image]

### The files are still there

```
sudo hexdump -C /dev/sda  | grep LUKS
```

outputs this:

```
00100000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 01  61 65 73 00 00 00 00 00  |LUKS....aes.....|
```

which means, that the LUKS header is still there.

Then I've mounted and decrypted the partition by running:

```
sudo losetup -o 0x00100000 -r -f /dev/sda
losetup -a
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop17 luksrecover
```

I was able to read all files on the disk.

### The question

How can I recreate the partition table of the LUKS partition?

Comment: You should be fine, as long as you don’t overwrite anything. You need to check the actual format of the LUKS header structure. The partition likely starts a little earlier.

Comment: That's great to hear! Can you provide more detail on how I can do that?

Comment: I see two ways to do this: Read the LUKS source code and find it there or create a LUKS container in a file and examine the result. Or it could be documented!

Comment: According to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411587/328716, the offset should be `0x00100000` in my case

Comment: @DanielB I've updated my question. I managed to read the files. But I'm not sure how to recreate the partition table

Comment: **Backups first!** You know the offset and the data is there - copy it to a file on an external drive or whatever. You don't want this to be your only copy of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to manually mount the drive and then copy all files to another disk.

### 1. Find the LUKS header

```
sudo hexdump -C /dev/sda  | grep LUKS
```

outputs this:

```
00100000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 01  61 65 73 00 00 00 00 00  |LUKS....aes.....|
```

which means, that the LUKS header is still there at `0x00100000`.

### 2. Mount the disk

Then I've mounted and decrypted the partition by running:

```
sudo losetup -o 0x00100000 -r -f /dev/sda
losetup -a | grep sda
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop17 luksrecover
```

### 3. Backup your files

Manually copy all files to another disk

Answer (score 0):

Acccording to your picture only your third partition is encrypted and the first and second partition are not. That situations allows the use of Testdisk to locate the missing partitions and to rewrite the partition table.

Comment: The first picture is actually a screenshot of another disk, because I did not have a before picture. The disk I'm trying to recover only had a LUKS partition